# Dividing on equal classes

Tags: r

I'm trying to create the percentage distribution of the number of the variable and draw a histogram of this distribution. I have to divide my variables on 9 equal ranges and sort them from lowest to biggest.

I was trying to use `hist(salary)` and sort it after all, but cannot do it right?
Any tips for making the ranges equal and sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You could `cut` your variable at `seq`uence with `range` as endpoints and length `10` (which gives `9` breaks). Then count the `length` in `g`roups using `tapply` and `barplot` the `proportions`.

```
dat <- transform(dat, g=cut(x, do.call(seq.int, c(as.list(range(x)), length.out=10)),
                            include.lowest=TRUE))
with(dat, tapply(x, g, length)) |> proportions() |> barplot()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 1e3
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 100, 25))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(santoku)
x <- rnorm(100)
barplot(proportions(tab_evenly(x, 9)))
```

[image]